# Print stdClass object from sub array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

Can someone please help me

`var_export($result);` output is

```
array (
  'ResponseCode' => '1',
  'ResponseText' => 'OK',
  'data' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'Credit' => '$1.9',
    )),
  ),
)
```

How can I just echo or print Credit value here .   I tried `print_r($result['data'] [0]);`  but i am getting output as

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Credit] => $1.9
)
```

Comment: `$result['data'][0]->Credit`?

Comment: Hi , i tried but it result same output  stdClass Object
(
    [Credit] => $1.9
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use it as following

```
$credit = $result['data'][0]->Credit;
```